# Mudar a cor do fundo do texto de um JTextArea

Tags: java, cores, editor-de-texto, jtextarea

Sou iniciante em Java e estou tentando criar uma função que mude o fundo das palavras, tirei um print do exemplo como gostaria que ficasse.
O esperado é que fique em exemplo uma tabela, mas a separação é por virgula.
Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço desde já.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fechei como duplicata pois isso não é possível com JTextArea, conforme diz a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html). Mas na resposta linkada é exemplificado como fazer a mesma coisa com o componente adequado pra isso.

Answer (score 0):

Para que dê um efeito de table, você vai ter que criar uma classe que vai herdar o `DefaultTableCellRenderer` e sobrescrever o método `getTableCellRendererComponent`

Você pode fazer como no exemplo abaixo, nesse ele muda além do fundo, a borda e a fonte.

```
private class TableRowHeaderCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
 @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 21 ));
        setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(SoftBevelBorder.RAISED));
        setBackground(new Color(244, 242, 228));
        setValue((String) value);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: TableCellrenderer em um JTextArea? Tem certeza que funciona?

Comment: Opa valeu... Mas não teria um jeito de ir mudando só a cor do fundo de algumas palavras da linha? Não quero criar uma tabela para isso.

Muito obrigado por me ajudar.